# How to access ios file system programmatically on PC?

Tags: ios, file, system

I'd like to know how to access ios file system on PC. It seems very complicated because I cannot find any useful information. But as far as I know, it is possible to achieve. I tried some file system management software such as iExplorer, iFile and DiskAid. Is there some expert who can give me some advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: PC software like iExplorer, iFile and DiskAid these stuff. I mean I want to make a program on PC which can access ios file system.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that may help, [Accessing HFS+ partitions from windows](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/02/access-mac-os-x-partition-from-windows.html%20Accessing%20OSX%20partitions%20from%20Windows), note that also if you have a Mac and have Boot Camp installed (with Apple's Boot Camp utilities) when booted into Windows you will also be able to access your Mac's hard drive.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get your answer. Does IOS portable device use HFS+? It seems that only mac os use HFS+. And I cannot open the link you provided.

Comment: I think you need HFSX (a case sensitive version of HFS+), which all iOS devices use (as far as I know).

Comment: Thanks! I will try to explore it.